# How to unfocused the current webpage in Microsoft Edge without using the mouse?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-edge, window-focus

I'm using Microsoft Edge as my browser, and I'm wondering if there are any keyboard shortcuts available that would allow me to unfocused the current webpage, similar to clicking on a blank area of the page. I prefer to navigate the browser without using the mouse, and this feature would greatly improve my browsing experience.

Comment: Do you mean to unselect the currently selected text on the page ?

Comment: Yes, include unselect the currently selected text, and also include, for example, I press alt, the focus will select the three dots in the upper right corner, the I want to loss focus, usually I would click on a blank area, but now I want to know if have some shortcut to do that.